# Django-allauth: send welcome email on signup (without verification)

Tags: django, django-allauth

How can I send a welcome email to a user who signs up on a django app(using django-allauth). If I set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = ("mandatory")`, it works fine, and the user gets a verification email. But since I dont require any email verification, so the user should simply signup and get a welcome email.

settings.py-

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = ("email")
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = ("none")
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION  = False
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SIGNUP = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED =True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET =False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = (ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED)
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AVATAR_SUPPORT = ( 'avatar' in INSTALLED_APPS)
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '##'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '##'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Is there any setting I missed which sends the welcome signup mail? Or do I have to pass it through my views? Cant seem to figure out the way for this. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No there is no such settings, but you can listen to a [user_signed_up](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/signals.py) signal, which will have the `user` and `request` in parameters. Once it received send an email to the user.

Put the below code some where in `models.py` file:

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_signed_up, dispatch_uid="some.unique.string.id.for.allauth.user_signed_up")
def user_signed_up_(request, user, **kwargs):
    # user signed up now send email
    # send email part - do your self
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! that worked!! To send the email I use  send_mail('Welcome', 'Your registration at abc.com is successful. Your username is %s' %user.username, 'Hello <hello@abc.com>', [user.email])
Although I don't know how to use a template here(not a single line of text) for the body of the email and I'll figure it out, your solution did the trick! Thanks

Comment: what is the use of dispatch_uid?

Comment: A unique identifier for a signal receiver in cases where duplicate signals may be sent. See [Preventing duplicate signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

allauth indeed only sends confirmation mails. But, it does differentiate between the first (signup) confirmation mail and following ones (e.g. when the user adds a second email address).

For this purpose allauth has a "email confirmation at signup"
 template (`account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.txt`, `account/email/email_confirmation_signup_subject.txt`).

When using the builtin templates this hybrid confirmation/signup/welcome mail is identical to the regular email confirmation template, but you can override it and put your welcome message in there. Furthermore, set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` to `"optional"`.

If all of this does not fit your needs, then you can hookup to the `user_signed_up` signal and send a plain welcome mail yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I cant use "optional" as I don't want to send the confirmation email on signup (even if the user doesnt verify). Perhaps Im using user_signed_up signal, that made it work.

Comment: can you share your user_signed_up signal?