# Django AllAuth - save session data after login/signup

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth, django-signals

How do I implement some logic immediately after a user is logged using Django-AllAuth?  Before I started implementing AllAuth, my login view contained this extra bit of logic after a user was logged in

```
...
login(request, user)

        # Check if the user has a league in session
        if 'league_id' in self.request.session:

            # Save the league to this user's user instance
            league_id = self.request.session.pop('league_id') # pop removes it from the session
            league = League.objects.get(pk = league_id)
            league.user = user
            league.save()
```

(The purpose here is that I'm allowing users to create a 'league' instance before logging in, and after they login the league gets associated to their user instance via a league_id stored in session.)

I tried extending the form_valid() method `LoginView` provided in allauth but it appears as though the form_valid() method never even gets called.

Any ideas how I can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [signals](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html).

There is a signal that is triggered right after an user is logged in: allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in

Comment: Sounds good, but I've never used signals before.  Could you give me example code (or pseudo code) or point me to an example elsewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928297/django-allauth-send-welcome-email-on-signup-without-verification